# How to stop C++ console closing immediately after first input

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, console

I have lately decided to take up learning c++ and it's been quite fun at first I encountered the problem of the console closing immediately after an output which could be solved by adding System("pause") now i have a program that has two inputs and after the first input the console closes without showing me any output and I couldn't fix it with system("pause").

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char name[50];
    int age;

    cout << "Please enter your name? ";
    cin >> name;


    cout << endl << "Okay, how old are you ? ";
    cin >> age;

    cout << "Nice to meet you, " << name << "!" endl;

    if (age < 10) cout << "Oh, you're quite young aren't you!" << endl; else
        if (age < 20) cout << "Embrace your teens they won't last long!" << endl else
            if (age < 40) cout << "Ah, I see you're still in your prime" << endl else
                if (age < 60) cout << "That's nice" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you use eclipse instead of micrsoft vs 2013 since eclipse doesn't close after this. Instead, it has a console at the bottom where stuff doesn't disappear after the program finishes.

Comment: Please note your code doesn't compile (missing ';') its important posting compile-able code so the readers could run it

Comment: Thanks for the reply I had tried eclipse but i got errors with cin, cout and std saying that they could not be resolved

Comment: @MapleSyrupFacial Try using eclipse again. I have used both of them and found eclipse more accommodating and less of those small little "mistakes" I have found with microsoft vs. Eclipse doesn't have any bad things such as this that I have found out.

Comment: Okay but when i use eclipse it tells me that cin, cout and std do not work and can not be resolved if you can tell me how to fix that i would probably use the program.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, run your program via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main () {

while (true) { 

system ("CLS"); //this will clear the screen of any text from prior run
cin.clear();    //this will clear any values remain in cin from prior run

body of your program goes here

system ("PAUSE");
} // this ends while loop
return 0;
} // this ends your main function.

I hope this helps.
```

Comment: It helps remembering that there is a system to use, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still want to use System("PAUSE")...

Try:

```
#include <cstdlib>

cout << endl << "Okay, how old are you ? ";
cin >> age;

cout << "Nice to meet you, " << name << "!" endl;
system("PAUSE");
```

Comment: There is no advantage to `system("PAUSE")` (or equivalent), and a number of problems. The problems include portability, inconvenient command line usage and obstruction of automation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use getch() in your program before the "return 0". The system will exit after you press a key.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Hello";
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```